# Rate of change of area of equilateral triangle

Tags: calculus

[image: ...]

The problem above appears in the book *Calculus for the practical man*. The solution section lists the correct answer as **60 square inches per minute**. However, I get a different solution. I wonder where (if anywhere) the error lies in my approach:

Let the length of the sides of the triangle be $x$ then $\frac{dx}{dt} = 10$ in./hour.

The area of the triangle is: $A = \frac{\sqrt 3}{4} x^2$ then $\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} x \, \frac{dx}{dt}$

Plugging in the specified values we get:

$\frac{dA}{dt}\Bigr|_{x = 69.28} = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \cdot 69.28 \cdot 10 \approx 600$ square inches per hour or $10$ square inches per minute.

Comment: I don't see an error in your work, it could be an error in the problem itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has a typo.  You can intuit this by just increasing $x$ by $10$ and looking at the change in area.  $x$ starts at about $70$ and increases to about $80$ over the next hour.  So the change is area is

$$\Delta A = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left(80^2 - 70^2\right) \approx  649.$$

So your answer makes much more sense than the book's.